# in wordpress can i impliment $sql in $metstyl

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mysqli

```
$metstyl= "SELECT concat(wtt.taxonomy,':' ,GROUP_CONCAT(wt.name separator ',')) as result 
        FROM `wp_term_taxonomy` as wtt, `wp_terms` as wt  
        where (wtt.taxonomy IN ('pa_metal','pa_style') AND wtt.term_id = wt.term_id AND wtt.count>0 AND )  
        group by taxonomy";

$sql = "select wtr.object_id 
        from `wp_terms`as wt , `wp_term_relationships` as wtr 
        where wt.slug='setting' AND wtr.term_taxonomy_id=wt.term_id";
```

Comment: Hello & Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit yoru question according to our rules. Please provide some text, some information. Show us what you exactly want (thats not clear at all right now) and show us what you've tried so far, and we'll help you.

Comment: there is a simple question how i am merge this two query

Comment: Started by the fact that there's 0,0 text -no, its not a question. Also you haven't showed at all what you've tried. Share your thoughts with us, show us what you've done till now and we'll help you. But nobody is gonna write code for you. Thats not how stackoverflow works.